# How to know BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector cmdlet return success or failure?

Tags: powershell

I have one machine with windows 10 operating system and this machine is not domain joined. My bit locker is enabled. Now i want to backup my recovery password using below code:

```
$BLV = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive
        $KeyProtectorID=""
        foreach($keyProtector in $BLV.KeyProtector){
            if($keyProtector.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword"){
                $KeyProtectorID=$keyProtector.KeyProtectorId
                break;
            }
        }

       $result = BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "$($env:SystemDrive)" -KeyProtectorId $KeyProtectorID
       if($result){
           return $true
       }
       if($Error){
           return $false
       }
       return $false
```

My question is, why it is not showing any error and return true value. Although it should show an error or $result should empty or false because my machine is not domain joined. Why $result contains a volume object while it should show any error or empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with try and catch block with -WhatIf argument in BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector cmdlet and i got the expected behavior

```
try{
$BLV = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive
        $KeyProtectorID=""
        foreach($keyProtector in $BLV.KeyProtector){
            if($keyProtector.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword"){
                $KeyProtectorID=$keyProtector.KeyProtectorId
                break;
            }
        }

       $result = BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "$($env:SystemDrive)" -KeyProtectorId $KeyProtectorID -whatif
return $true
}
catch{
     return $false
}
```

Also check with this below link:
[Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector doesn't return any error even if it fails?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/656b5803-2f76-4957-afd1-63c7759e86fb/backupbitlockerkeyprotector-doesnt-return-any-error-even-if-it-fails?forum=mdopmbam)